# Open a local PDF file in Safari browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a PDF file in my application bundle which I'd like to open in Safari. Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is posible to open documents in external applications. Check out [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class, it's simple as this:

```
// you'll need to keep it around
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;

(...)

NSURL *fileUrl = // URL to your pdf file
self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
self.docController.delegate = self;
[self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero
                                       inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

That said, the pdf will be offered to be opened in iBooks, as Safari apparently doesn't boast of pdf reading capability :) So if you insist on having Safari open your pdf, it might be tricky.

Comment: I knw how to display file in in our application but i want to oen pdf file in safari browser same as when we enter any url of pdf and open safari will display that file.

Comment: My answer isn't about opening pdf in **your** application, but in a **system** application that handles pdf files. In iOS this is the iBooks spp. `UIDocumentInteractionController` would actually show you the list of applications that support opening pdfs incoming from other apps like yours.

Comment: thanx this works but is it possible to get the list of all the application and open the pdf in selected application without displaying the action sheet?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose sandboxing makes this inherently difficult. One solution is to upload the PDF to a server and then open that URL instead. Otherwise I doubt it would work.

Comment: Remember jailbreaking was due to PDF vulnerabilty..... open a PDF and device breaks :P

Comment: there is an another option but is it possible to open local pdf file in browser bcz it will also working in offline mode